# Need CSS/HTML advice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have a slight problem if you go to,

http://bdsfineandrare.co.uk/website/index.php.html

you will see the content area on the home page on the right hand side automatically shows.

could anyone help me on making it so it doesn't show until someone clicks the cross in the top right to make it show.

at the moment, it automatically appears and when you click on the "x" it hides. i would like that feature reversed so you have to click it to show so it automatically is hidden when visited.

The template im using is "KOSE html"

Thanks Ever So Much

Comment: You have to post your code here

Comment: in kose.js file, make `var isContentHidden = true;`. In your html add css class 'rotated' to '#hide-toggle-button'. In your css kose.css file, `#content-container` put `display:none`. Save all files and try :)

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) instead.

Comment: Thanks it works perfect, can you help me make it only happen on one page not on all of them.

thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Add the below CSS to your page:

```
#content-container{
  display:none;
}
```

For conformity, also add `class="rotated` to your `hide-toggle-button` link in your HTML:

```
<a href="index.php.html#" id="hide-toggle-button" class="rotated"><i class="icon ion-ios7-close-empty"></i></a>
```

Comment: You need to change kose.js file as well.. read my comment under the question.

Comment: This is perfect it works fine, but it changes every other page not just the page i want. thanks a lot for helping me! i really appreciate it.